# Is it possible to call a non activity class from a BroadcastReceiver, If yes how we can do?

Tags: android

I have one BroadcastReceiver,it notify when phone state is changed, at that time i wan't to get a data from `CallLog.Calls`(this reside in my non activity class) and save it to my SQLite database.But now i facing a problem when calling a class.
Since i am new to android, any help or idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could start an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) from your BroadcastReceiver and from there do whatever you want.

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {             
        mContext = context;     
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));     
    }

    public static class UpdateService extends IntentService {

        public UpdateService() {
            super("UpdateService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {      
            // Do whatever you want from here
            Logic.doSomething(mContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Add the service to your manifest.

```
<service android:name="com.example.UpdateReceiver$UpdateService" />
```

Comment: Your code gives following error
 WARN/ActivityManager(65): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.example/.UpdateReceiver$UpdateService }: not found

Comment: You need to add the service to your manifest. I've updated my answer.